# unable to update python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

When I type `python --versio`n,  the output is "`Python 2.7.18`" I tried `python3 --version`, and the output is `Python 3.10.4`, how can update python to 3.10 without creating python 3?

I was expecting python's version to be 3.10.x and I tried brew upgrade, it didn't work. I'm on mac montery btw

Comment: set in env accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
`vi ~/.bash`
```

Then type out

```
alias python=python3
```

Save your file by pressing `Esc` -> type `:wq`

Then to update your shell environment

```
source ~/.bash
```

Another way you could try if you know what you are doing, is to go straight to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` and write direct into it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@X.Y/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

change `X` and `Y` to your python version

Answer (score 0):

Linux based system comes with Python 2 pre-installed for compatibility with legacy software. It's not recommended to make changes on it yourself. You might be breaking something.

For now, if you want to use Python 3, your option is to use the python3 command.

Alternatively, you may try the recently released (march, 14th) macOS Monterey 12.3. Acordinly to it's [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes), they are dropping the python 2 from the system. In this case, you should be able to safely install Python 3 and use it as just python at the command line.

Comment: The answer declared some reason why python2 should not be changed. But the asker may want to find a way to using python command to refer the python3, and alias may be what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The python 2 version is used by the system and it's recommended that you don't mess with it becauseyoua can seriously damage your ability to use your operatingsystem.

If you feel like you need to manage multiple python versions in your system you can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

This article [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) also simplifies the installation